# How to limit recursions? - Laravel/Blade

Tags: php, laravel

My website has articles, and these articles have comments. Comments can have child comments, and those comments can have child comments, pretty much going on forever.

In my `Comment.php` model, child comments are organized through a hasMany relationship:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','parent_id');
}
```

In my controller, I get the comments that don't have a parent like so:

```
$comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)->where('parent_id', NULL)->get();
```

and then I `foreach` them in the blade view:

```
<div class="comment-thread-container">
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @include('partials.comment_block')  
@endforeach
</div>
```

What's included is a Sub-View called `comment-block.blade.php` that is called for each comment.

Inside this sub-view is ANOTHER `foreach` that calls that comment's children:

```
@foreach ($comment->children as $comment)
<div style="margin-left: 8px">
    @include('partials.comment_block')
</div>
@endforeach
```

Essentially, this can go on forever. However, I don't want it to.

I want to make it so that, for example, if a comment has 10 generations of parents (so a comment would have a child, and that comment would have a child, etc. etc. 10 times), it would stop and show a link with something like "Show Entire Thread" that would link to it's own page.

However, I don't how to I could do this. What would be the most elegant way to count the recursions?

Reddit does this pretty well, and for those who don't quite understand my question then this image might help:

[image: reddit]

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the view or the controller?

Comment: I'd look at it another way: "count the recursions" really just means "probe the depth of that branch" since you're really dealing with a one-sided tree. At that point, elegance has gone out the window but there are several tried-and-true methods for traversing tree structures. You'd probably want a depth-first traversal and to count along the way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, in Blade templates, a `$loop` variable is automatically created in every `@foreach` statement.

One of the many properties this variable has is `$loop->depth`.

This will count the nesting level of the current loop.

So in my case, when a nesting loop reaches `10`, I simply `@break` the recursion.

```
@foreach ($comment->children as $comment)
    @if ($loop->depth == 10)
        @include('partials.comment_end')
        @break
    @else
        <div style="margin-left: 8px">
            @include('partials.comment_block')
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable